# ¿que se pone en el link en la funcion cell de fpdf?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, fpdf

[image]
Quiero saber lo que se pone en la variable $link para poder agregar datos desde un BD un reporte en php

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de problemas, por lo general, se solucionan leyendo el [manual](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/index.php).
Según el manual:

[`Cell()`](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/cell.htm)

> **link**:
> URL o identificador retornado por AddLink().

Es decir, acepta:

- Una *cadena*, por ejemplo:

  ```
  $link = 'http://www.fpdf.org/';
  $fpdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Titulo', 1, 1,'C', false, $link);
  ```
- O una *referencia interna* retornada por `AddLink`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  //...
  $ref = $fpdf->AddLink();
  $fpdf->Write(5, 'clic aca', $ref);

  //... segunda página
  $fpdf->AddPage();
  $fpdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Titulo', 1, 1,'C', false, $ref);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Si el elemento a agregar es un enlace, ahi debes insertar la url del mismo.

Si solo es un texto plano, puedes no enviar ese parámetro o bien enviar una cadena vacía.